# Deleting all pending tasks in celery / rabbitmq

Tags: task, rabbitmq, celery, celery-task

How can I delete all pending tasks without knowing the `task_id` for each task?

Answer (score 403, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=purge#how-do-i-purge-all-waiting-tasks):

```
$ celery -A proj purge
```

or

```
from proj.celery import app
app.control.purge()
```

(EDIT: Updated with current method.)

Comment: Or, from Django, for celery 3.0+: `manage.py celery purge` (`celeryctl` is now deprecated and will be gone in 3.1).

Comment: I found this answer looking for how to do this with a redis backend. Best method I found was `redis-cli KEYS "celery*" | xargs redis-cli DEL` which worked for me. This will wipe out all tasks stored on the redis backend you're using.

Comment: How can i do this in celery 3.0 ?

Comment: For me, it was simply `celery purge` (inside the relevant virtual env). Ooops - there's an answer with the same below..... http://stackoverflow.com/a/20404976/1213425

Comment: For Celery 4.0+ in combination with Django it's again this command, where the argument to `-A` is the Django app where the `celery.py` is located.

Comment: this doesn't work on scheduled task. after such a `purge` you can still see them scheduled and they WILL run when their. time comes (you can see them with `inspect scheduled`)

Comment: No idea why, but this just seems to endlessly hang for me. To deal with it, I used `redis-cli --bigkeys` to find the biggest keys, which happened to be my queue names. I `DEL`'ed those keys in redis, and things seem to be OK. This is deletes your whole queue, but I was OK doing that.

Answer (score 152):

For celery 3.0+:

```
$ celery purge
```

To purge a specific queue:

```
$ celery -Q queue_name purge
```

Comment: If you get connection errors, make sure you specify the app, e.g. `celery -A proj purge`.

Comment: I believe the -Q flag has been deprecated (didn't work for me, "no such option"), to delete a specific queue on Celery 5.0.5 you'd run celery -A appname purge --queues queuename

Answer (score 33):

#### For Celery 2.x and 3.x:

When using worker with -Q parameter to define queues, for example

```
celery worker -Q queue1,queue2,queue3
```

then `celery purge` will not work, because you cannot pass the queue params to it. It will only delete the default queue.
The solution is to start your workers with `--purge` parameter like this:

```
celery worker -Q queue1,queue2,queue3 --purge
```

This will however run the worker.

Other option is to use the amqp subcommand of celery

```
celery amqp queue.delete queue1
celery amqp queue.delete queue2
celery amqp queue.delete queue3
```

Comment: Yes, this is for older (2.x and maybe 3.x) versions of celery. I cannot edit the answer

Answer (score 19):

In Celery 3+:

CLI:

```
$ celery -A proj purge
```

Programatically:

```
>>> from proj.celery import app
>>> app.control.purge()
```

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-purge-all-waiting-tasks

Answer (score 10):

I found that `celery purge` doesn't work for my more complex celery config.  I use multiple named queues for different purposes:

```
$ sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues -p celery name messages consumers
Listing queues ...  # Output sorted, whitespaced for readability
celery                                          0   2
celery@web01.celery.pidbox                      0   1
celery@web02.celery.pidbox                      0   1
apns                                            0   1
apns@web01.celery.pidbox                        0   1
analytics                                       1   1
analytics@web01.celery.pidbox                   0   1
bcast.361093f1-de68-46c5-adff-d49ea8f164c0      0   1
bcast.a53632b0-c8b8-46d9-bd59-364afe9998c1      0   1
celeryev.c27b070d-b07e-4e37-9dca-dbb45d03fd54   0   1
celeryev.c66a9bed-84bd-40b0-8fe7-4e4d0c002866   0   1
celeryev.b490f71a-be1a-4cd8-ae17-06a713cc2a99   0   1
celeryev.9d023165-ab4a-42cb-86f8-90294b80bd1e   0   1
```

The first column is the queue name, the second is the number of messages waiting in the queue, and the third is the number of listeners for that queue.  The queues are:

- celery - Queue for standard, idempotent celery tasks
- apns - Queue for Apple Push Notification Service tasks, not quite as idempotent
- analytics - Queue for long running nightly analytics
- *.pidbox - Queue for worker commands, such as shutdown and reset, one per worker (2 celery workers, one apns worker, one analytics worker)
- bcast.* - Broadcast queues, for sending messages to all workers listening to a queue (rather than just the first to grab it)
- celeryev.* - Celery event queues, for reporting task analytics

The analytics task is a brute force tasks that worked great on small data sets, but now takes more than 24 hours to process.  Occasionally, something will go wrong and it will get stuck waiting on the database.  It needs to be re-written, but until then, when it gets stuck I kill the task, empty the queue, and try again.  I detect "stuckness" by looking at the message count for the analytics queue, which should be 0 (finished analytics) or 1 (waiting for last night's analytics to finish).  2 or higher is bad, and I get an email.

`celery purge` offers to erase tasks from one of the broadcast queues, and I don't see an option to pick a different named queue.

Here's my process:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd stop  # Wait for analytics task to be last one, Ctrl-C
$ ps -ef | grep analytics  # Get the PID of the worker, not the root PID reported by celery
$ sudo kill <PID>
$ sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd stop  # Confim dead
$ python manage.py celery amqp queue.purge analytics
$ sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues -p celery name messages consumers  # Confirm messages is 0
$ sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd start
```

Comment: Not an answer though, is it? Very informative however!

Comment: `celeryctl purge` didn't work with named queues.  `python manage.py celery amqp queue.purge <queue_name>` did.  I think the context is useful for those with complex setups, so they can figure out what they need to do if `celeryctl purge` fails for them.

Comment: I cannot find `manage.py` in my Celery 3.1.17, has the file been removed or just spanking new? I found what looks like the corresponding interface (`queue.purge`) in `*/bin/amqp.py`, however. But after trying to correlate the contents of the file with the documentation, I must regrettably admit that Celery is woefully undocumented and also a *very* convoluted piece of work, at least judging it by its source code.

Comment: `manage.py` is the Django management script, and `manage.py celery` runs celery after loading configuration from Django settings.  I haven't used celery outside of Django, but the included `celery` command may be what you are looking for: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html

Answer (score 9):

If you want to remove all pending tasks and also the active and reserved ones to completely stop Celery, this is what worked for me:

```
from proj.celery import app
from celery.task.control import inspect, revoke

# remove pending tasks
app.control.purge()

# remove active tasks
i = inspect()
jobs = i.active()
for hostname in jobs:
    tasks = jobs[hostname]
    for task in tasks:
        revoke(task['id'], terminate=True)

# remove reserved tasks
jobs = i.reserved()
for hostname in jobs:
    tasks = jobs[hostname]
    for task in tasks:
        revoke(task['id'], terminate=True)
```

Comment: If you also want to revoke scheduled tasks, ie, those waiting due to an `eta` or `countdown`, you also need to revoke tasks in the `i.scheduled()` queue. For these, the `id` is inside a `request` key (at least for me on Redis), ie, you need to run `revoke(task['request']['id'])`. Also, for me on Celery 5.2.7 in Django at least, I needed to run `app.control.inspect`, and `app.control.revoke` - I couldn't import them independently (got an unbound error). My final code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73129412/1308967).

Answer (score 8):

In Celery 3+

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/faq.html#how-do-i-purge-all-waiting-tasks

*CLI*

Purge named queue:

```
 celery -A proj amqp queue.purge <queue name>
```

Purge configured queue

```
celery -A proj purge
```

> I’ve purged messages, but there are still messages left in the queue?
>   Answer: Tasks are acknowledged (removed from the queue) as soon as they are actually executed. After the worker has received a task, it will take some time until it is actually executed, especially if there are a lot of tasks already waiting for execution. Messages that are not acknowledged are held on to by the worker until it closes the connection to the broker (AMQP server). When that connection is closed (e.g. because the worker was stopped) the tasks will be re-sent by the broker to the next available worker (or the same worker when it has been restarted), so to properly purge the queue of waiting tasks you have to stop all the workers, and then purge the tasks using celery.control.purge().

So to purge the entire queue workers must be stopped.

Answer (score 5):

For Celery 5.0+, to do it from the CLI and to target a specific queue:

`celery -A APP_NAME purge --queues QUEUE_NAME`

Add `-f` option to the end to skip the confirmation step if you're trying to do it in on step like I was.

Answer (score 4):

**celery 4+** 
celery purge command to purge all configured task queues

```
celery -A *APPNAME* purge
```

**programmatically:**

```
from proj.celery import app
app.control.purge()
```

all pending task will be purged.
Reference: [celerydoc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/4.0/faq.html?highlight=purge#how-do-i-purge-all-waiting-tasks)

Answer (score 2):

1.
To properly purge the queue of waiting tasks you have to stop all the workers (http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#i-ve-purged-messages-but-there-are-still-messages-left-in-the-queue):

```
$ sudo rabbitmqctl stop
```

or (in case RabbitMQ/message broker is managed by Supervisor):

```
$ sudo supervisorctl stop all
```

2. 
...and then purge the tasks from a specific queue:

```
$ cd <source_dir>
$ celery amqp queue.purge <queue name>
```

3.
Start RabbitMQ:

```
$ sudo rabbitmqctl start
```

or (in case RabbitMQ is managed by Supervisor):

```
$ sudo supervisorctl start all
```

Answer (score 2):

For Celery Version 5.0+ with RabbitMQ as broker

We need establish a new connection from program to broker first,
and bind the connection with the queues to purge.

```
# proj/celery.py
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('proj')
```

```py
from proj.celery import app
queues = ['queue_A', 'queue_B', 'queue_C']
with app.connection_for_write() as conn:
    conn.connect()
    for queue in queues:
        count = app.amqp.queues[queue].bind(conn).purge()
        print(f'Purge {queue} with {count} message(s)')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that may have solved it. the old tasks were still in django-celery-beat>periodic tasks in my django admin, so go to django admin page and delete all of them, then if you are in docker container, restart the it all the problem solved