# Remove unregistered task from celerybeat

Tags: django, celery, celerybeat

When I was trying to figure out how celery works or more specifically how it works with Django, I added [the example CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE setting](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries) to my settings file. It added task.add to my task queue. I have since removed that setting yet it keeps trying to add that task. I am getting thousands of error reports each day in sentry that say:

```
Received unregistered task of type u'tasks.add'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
More: http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#names

The full contents of the message body was:
{'utc': True, 'chord': None, 'args': [16, 16], 'retries': 0, 'expires': None, 'task': u'tasks.add', 'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'taskset': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'eta': None, 'id': '6d609a07-fbfa-4d6e-aa21-46e779c159c0'} (198b)
```

How do I get celertbeat to stop trying to add this task?

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer here [Stopping/Purging Periodic Tasks in Django-Celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230833/stopping-purging-periodic-tasks-in-django-celery). I found the rogue tasks in my Django Admin under periodic tasks. Though I had looked there a dozen times I was looking for task.add instead of 'add-ever-30-seconds'.

After delete the periodic task record I then purged my celery queue: [Deleting all pending tasks in celery / rabbitmq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149074/deleting-all-pending-tasks-in-celery-rabbitmq)